# Trying to delete files from documents directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, directory

I have an app that allows users to record multiple videos and then post them to view later from a database. After they post the video, I want the app to delete the video from the documents directory to save phone storage. I am trying this, but when i check my phone's storage nothing is updated. Here is what I am doing

This is where i write the video to:

```
func videoFileLocation() -> String {
    let uniqueID = NSUUID().uuidString
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let outputPath = "\(documentsPath)/\(uniqueID).mov"
    return outputPath
}
```

This is how I remove them:

```
func clearDirectory() {
    do {
        data = try context.fetch(VideoPath.fetchRequest())

        for each in data {
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let path = "\(documentsPath)/\(each.fileLocations!)"
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
                print("Successfully Cleared")
            } catch {
                print("There was a problem removing the file")
            }
}
```

The successfully cleared method gets printed out, but I see no change in my phone's storage. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of each.fileLocations? I bet it's a full path instead of just a filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
let path = "\(documentsPath)/\(each.fileLocations!)"
```

with below and try.

```
var path: String = nil

if let fileLocationPath = each.fileLocations as? String {
  path = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(fileLocationPath)
}
```

Comment: That still didn't change anything within my storage it keeps going up. Is there away to clear the whole directory?

Comment: Workaround is to delete the app and install again till we find the solution.

Comment: Did you try printing the path is it same as where you save the file

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the only way to fix it, but do you have any other suggestions for the solution @Joe

Comment: I'll check that now

Comment: Yes they match the URL

Comment: Haha i fixed it, there was an extra slash mark somewhere